# How do you pass a React callback function to a typescript object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, callback

I have a singleton class in `Daemon.ts`

```js
export default class Daemon {
    
    private static instance : Daemon;
    callback : (tstring : string)=>void;
    t : number;

    constructor (callback: (tstring : string)=>void){
        this.data = data
        this.callback = callback;
        this.t = 0;
        window.setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)
    }

    public static getInstance(callback: (tstring : string)=>void){
        if(!Daemon.instance){ Daemon.instance = new Daemon(callback);}
        return Daemon.instance;
    }

    tick(){
        this.t = this.t + 1
        this.callback(this.t.toString());
    }

}
```

Then in a separate file, `Timefeedback.tsx`, I have:

```js
const TimeFeedback = () => {

    const [time, updateSimTime] = React.useState<string>("starting string");
    
    const updateTime = (tString : string) => {
      updateSimTime(tString);
      console.log(`update time called, val: ${tString}`)
    }

    const daemon = Daemon.getInstance(updateTime.bind(this));
  
    return (
      <div>
        {time}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

What I expect to happen:

- the time state is updated on each tick() from the daemon.

What actually happens:

- the callback function `updateTime` is successfully called, and the console log prints the correct values. But the setState function updateTime()
  What happens is I get console logs from `TimeFeedback.tsx` with the expected value of `tString` printed out. But the setState function `setSimTime` never gets called, so the text in the div remains "starting time". Why is this?

I have investigated, when calling print events inside of Daemon I get:

```
function() {
    [native code]
}
```

I tried to remove the `.bind(this)` inside  `TimeFeedback.tsx`, but nothing changes except the print instead says:

```
tString => {
    setSimTime(tString);
    console.log(`update time called, val: ${tString}`);
  }
```

I also walked through with the debugger and `updateSimTime` *does* get called but it has no effect.

Why is that `updateSimTime` has no effect?

Comment: What is `data` in the `constructor`?

Comment: Works fine when I remove `this.data = data` https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-julien-yzkgwj?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: `updateTime.bind(this)` doesn't make sense in a function component because a function component doesn't have a `this` like a class component does.

Comment: ah this is a simplified version of the class I'm working with and the data `data` field was accidentally left in after I pasted it over

Comment: @Konrad the problem is replicated when `Daemon` is in a separate .ts file, it appears if `Daemon` is in the same file as the `TimeFeedback` it'll work just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No need to `.bind` in the component

`updateTime.bind(this)` doesn't make sense in a function component because a function component doesn't have a `this` like a class component does.  Your `updateTime` function can be passed directly to the `Daemon.getInstance` function.

You also need to remove the `this.data = data` in the `Daemon` constructor because there is no `data` variable` (as pointed out by @Konrad in the comments).

As a best practice, I would recommend moving the code into a `useEffect` hook.

```
const TimeFeedback = () => {
  const [time, updateSimTime] = useState<string>("starting string");

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateTime = (tString: string) => {
      updateSimTime(tString);
      console.log(`update time called, val: ${tString}`);
    };
  
    Daemon.getInstance(updateTime);
  }, [updateSimTime]);

  return <div>{time}</div>;
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-haze-q6fxly)